# Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot

Tags: boot

After moving my hard drive to a new computer the boot process freezes in the following portions of the dmesg:

```
[   10.165412] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   15.331876] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

---

```
[   15.992665] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   15.997006] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
[   16.118129] input: Logitech M215 2nd Gen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:401B.0004/input/input20
[   16.118255] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:401B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M215 2nd Gen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2:1
[   16.122221] input: Logitech K360 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4004.0005/input/input21
[   16.122407] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4004.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech K360] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2:2
[   99.019230] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

---

```
[  106.368989] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[  107.511022] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[  108.942390] wlp4s0: authenticate with e4:f4:c6:0c:83:c2
[  108.945676] wlp4s0: send auth to e4:f4:c6:0c:83:c2 (try 1/3)
[  108.947515] wlp4s0: authenticated
[  108.953618] wlp4s0: associate with e4:f4:c6:0c:83:c2 (try 1/3)
[  108.957515] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from e4:f4:c6:0c:83:c2 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=4)
[  108.961532] wlp4s0: associated
[  108.962064] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[  140.532941] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: Unknown ELD version 0
[  140.534707] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: Unknown ELD version
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/837721/103660) to a similar question. 
Among all other problems there can be an invalid entry in /etc/fstab.