# Is Bluetooth responsible for my Ubuntu 16.04 much slower startup?

Tags: boot, startup

I've recently upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04 to Xubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo T450s. The upgrade was uneventful and the system's been running very well, so kudos to the dev team behind it.

However the startup and shutdown times have been extended by about 40-50 seconds. Blame is not showing the culprit:

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze blame

  6.961s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  1.920s docker.service
   767ms dev-sda1.device
   324ms gpu-manager.service
```

However, **dmesg** appears to point at the bluetooth subsystem:

```
[3.807429] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan1: renamed from wlan0
[6.037784] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint
[6.235993] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as 
[92.865487] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[92.865491] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[92.865496] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Has anyone else experience this? Any suggestions how to fix the problem?

(I already checked other suggestions like swap partition having a different UUID in fstab vs blkid)

Comment: Did you try rebooting with disabled bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, from the OS menu. It gets turn right back on.  I can try disabling in BIOS I suppose. My mouse is bluetooth so I'm hoping there is another way though.

Comment: I have the same Bluetooth-entries from `dmesg` without having a slow boot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not necessarily related to the Bluetooth. Something slow is happening during those two `dmesg` rows.

I had the same problem after a fresh install to a new SSD drive. It turned out that during the install process Ubuntu found the older HDD's swap partition and registered that in `/etc/fstab`.
After I have removed the older HDD the swap partition was naturally not available and Ubuntu was waiting there for more than a minute **without any `dmesg` row to appear**. When I deleted the HDD's swap partition from `/etc/fstab` the boot became less than 10 seconds.

You may have the same cause or some hardware- but non necessarily Bluetooth-related problem.

Comment: That was the culprit in my case as well. I used to have an encrypted partition which I later dropped. However, during the upgrade process to 16.04 the encrypted partition's entry got re-injected into fstab causing my boot slow-down (timeout had to occur before moving on). Since your observation matches my case, I'm marking as Answered by you. Thanks for sharing!