# Splash screen is loading really slow (details below)

Tags: boot, bluetooth, startup

I reinstalled Ubuntu over another install and now the boot time takes about 1 minute and 40 seconds just on the splash screen. I believe it has something to do with the former swap partition.

my dmesg output:

https://pastebin.com/0a5zx1Vr

my /etc/fstab open in gedit:

IN LINK BELOW, HAD TO REMOVE BECAUSE I AM A PLEB :(

I am going off this post: [Is Bluetooth responsible for my Ubuntu 16.04 much slower startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826000/is-bluetooth-responsible-for-my-ubuntu-16-04-much-slower-startup)

but i have little idea on which one to delete, I guess the first but I don't feel like breaking my system again. In the above post we have the same issue I just do not know which one to delete in geddit, I have tried contacting both users and no luck.

EDIT: Here are all the commands and their outputs: https://pastebin.com/f2m9nY46

What I mean by older swap partition is basically what I read in the post above: "I had the same problem after a fresh install to a new SSD drive. It turned out that during the install process Ubuntu found the older HDD's swap partition and registered that in /etc/fstab." Since I had another installation of ubuntu on the drive before this one I thought it might be applicable.

Comment: Please describe "former swap partition"? Show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/crypttab`. Please copy/paste the info into your question, not the comment please .Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Comment: @heynnema The edit is there mate

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. Is your /home folder encrypted? If not, is there a need for an encrypted swap? Are there any other disks to consider besides a primary SSD?

Comment: @heynnema there is only one disk and it is an HDD. The /home folder is encrypted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two encrypted swap locations defined, but only 1 physical swap partition. We'll comment out the extra swap. We'll make backups so that if things don't work as planned, we can always recover easily.

**Edit /etc/fstab...**

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak # backup fstab
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab # edit fstab
```

Change this line:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

To this:

```
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

**Edit /etc/crypttab...**

```
sudo cp /etc/crypttab /etc/crypttab.bak # backup crypttab
gksudo gedit /etc/crypttab # edit crypttab
```

Change this line:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=211081f4-558e-41f4-9b94-337b10845122 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

To this (I'm not 100% sure that crypttab will accept a #, and if not, we should just remove this line):

```
 #cryptswap1 UUID=211081f4-558e-41f4-9b94-337b10845122 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Reboot the computer.

Comment: @HardlyTheJavaLegend have you tried it yet?

Comment: yep everything worked, it boots like it did before all my screwups, many thanks :p

Comment: You're fast! Glad it worked. If you like, you can just delete those two lines that we commented out. And in both files change cryptswap2 to cryptswap1... just to make it all look nice.

Comment: +1 to both of you for quickly figuring this out. It help makes this site a valuable global commodity.